# Can't call method in another class - ANDROID

Tags: java, android

recently i opened a question about how to call a method in another class... ok, i did call the example method, but the method i really want to call isn't working:

I have 2 classes:

I want to call the method here: `TelaCadastroRestaurante.java`

I have the method here: `Metodos.java`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcFa3.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBeCr.png

---

public class TelaCadastroRestaurante extends Activity {

```
private EditText nomeRestaurante, emailRestaurante, telefoneRestaurante;
private Button buttonProximo;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela_cadastro_restaurante);
    incializarComponentes();
    acaoBotoes();
}

public void incializarComponentes() {
    nomeRestaurante = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNomeRestauranteTelaCadastroRestaurante);
    emailRestaurante = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmailRestauranteTelaCadastroRestaurante);
    telefoneRestaurante = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTelefoneRestauranteTelaCadastroRestaurante);
    buttonProximo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonProximoTelaCadastroRestaurante);

}

public void acaoBotoes() {
    buttonProximo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Metodos metodos = new Metodos();
            Metodos.taskInProgres(true, getApplicationContext());       
        }
    });
}

public void pegarValores(){

    Restaurante rest = new Restaurante();

    rest.setNomeRest(nomeRestaurante.getText().toString());
    rest.setEmailRest(emailRestaurante.getText().toString());
    rest.setTelefoneRest(Integer.parseInt(telefoneRestaurante.getText().toString()));

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rest.getNomeRest() + "\n" +  rest.getEmailRest() + "\n" + rest.getTelefoneRest(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

**CLASS WITH METHODS**

public class Metodos {

```
private static ProgressDialog dialog;

public static void taskInProgres(boolean mostrar, Context context) {

    if (dialog == null) {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "","Aguarde a verificação...", true);
    }
    if (mostrar) {
        dialog.show();
    } else {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please include the code *in the question*, tell us what you've tried, and what went wrong.

Comment: ... and your expected outcome - "isn't working" is neither a sufficient requirement nor issue description

Comment: @gknicker do you want me to put the LogCat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `xMetodos.java` class change the method to be static :

`private static void...` and in `TelaCadastroRestaurante.java` class call it like this :

`xMetodos.taskInProgres(true,getApplicationContext());`

If you declared method as `static` you can call it without  instantiating it.

Comment: i did what you told me, but still isn't working:

http://i.imgur.com/YHAYEIF.png - CLASS WITH METHOD

http://i.imgur.com/Lk4geMb.png - CLASS THAT I WANT TO CALL THE METHOD

Comment: In `xMetodos.java`  try putting the `dialog` object in the method itself

Comment: you mean, create the dialog object inside of the method?

Comment: yehhhh - @ Luis Henrique Valgoi

Comment: yehhhh - @ Luis Henrique Valgoi

Comment: Ok, so here we go... i got 
http://i.imgur.com/NjES8Bd.png 

AND 

http://i.imgur.com/nHnszht.png

BUT here is the error

http://i.imgur.com/dsN3cpi.png

Comment: The class`xMetodos.java` should be under the same package of `TelaCadastroRestaurante.java` put it where `TelaCadastroRestaurante.java` is.

Comment: ok, i moved all the class to the same package.. but again, the error still persist:

http://i.imgur.com/L4sUETr.png - ACTIVITY
http://i.imgur.com/bRc7sXH.png - METHODS
http://i.imgur.com/MiN3hx8.png - ERROR

Comment: What is line 38 in `TelaCadastroRestaurante.java`?

Comment: Change this line : `xMetodos.taskInProgres(true,getApplicationContext());` to : `xMetodos.taskInProgres(true,TelaCadastroRestaurante.this);`

Comment: That's what happens when you use this from inside of an inner class. If you want to reference the instance of an outer class, you must specify so, as you do with OuterClass.this. Just using this always references the most inner class' instance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make an instance of `class` `xMethodos` to be able to call the method.

Code would look like:

```
xMethodos foo = new xMethodos ():
foo.taskInProgress([YOUR_BOOL], [YOUR_CONTEXT);
```

Where the context would probably your activity, which can be reffered to as `this`.